# What will the results be if I electrolyzed brine with these materials?

Tags: electrolysis

I have tried electrolyzing saltwater (brine) with copper electrodes, but I got a rusty sludge and hydrogen being produced at the anode. I read about it and it is just dissolved copper, possibly oxidized. What will the results be, if I used the following materials?

- Aluminium foil
- Iron
- Pencil graphite

Comment: First check your assumptions. It is anode, not cathode, where copper gets oxidized and dissolved. Now, other metals are going to be oxidized as well (and even more readily). Graphite may be a good choice, in that it's more inert.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I will then do Graphite. I heard that platinum is the best electrode. This is however too expensive. 10 grams for about 300$. I tried aluminum foil recently, but that seemed to produce Hydrogen and Oxygen...